# kSOAP - Works fine on Wifi but fails on slow/congested GPRS network

Tags: android, android-ksoap2

I've another question regarding this issue too but I'm kinda getting desperate now.

This is a HUGE problem and I'm surprised why this hasn't been discussed much before..

So, I'm using kSOAP2-android in my application to call certain SOAP services. They work fine when on Wifi, but as soon as I shift to GPRS, most of the time the service calls fail and return with a SocketTimeoutException.

I've tried some of the things I read on the internet like putting a timeout value (I tried 3000ms) or using the

```
System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
```

before making the http call.

However, nothing's working. At times everything works fine but as soon as the net gets busy, everything falls apart. Almost 90% of the calls fail with the timeout exception.

And no, internet works fine for apps like Facebook Messenger, Gmail etc (though browsing struggles).

Is there anything I can try?

Answer (score 0):

Check out

http://developer.android.com/training/efficient-downloads/efficient-network-access.html#RadioStateMachine

2000ms is only radio latency.  May be trying larger values than 3000ms will help?

Comment: Doesn't help. I've tried with the default 20s timeout as well.